# Trying to get a random number with a chance to get that number

Tags: php, mysql, random

I tried to create this, but it does not really work.

Here is the table of how I want it to work..
[click to see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xyem.png)

Here is a picture of my database (in phpmyadmin) [click to see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do1to.png)

I want it to first look at the percentages, and find which one to use.

IE: 75% chance to get a random number between 1 and 50. 20% chance for a random number between 51 and 200 etc.

---

Here is my code:

```
if ($_GET['method'] == "test") {
    $sql = "SELECT 1percentage, 1min, 1max, 2percentage, 2min, 2max, 3percentage, 3min, 3max, 4percentage, 4min, 4max FROM `keys`";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $total = $row["1percentage"] + $row["2percentage"] + $row["3percentage"] + $row["4percentage"] + 1;
            $random = rand(0, $total);
            if ($random < $row['1percentage'] || $random == $row['1percentage']) {
                $amount = rand($row['1min'], $row['1max']);
            } elseif ($random > $row['1percentage'] && $random < $row['2percentage'] || $random == $row['2percentage']) {
                $amount = rand($row['2min'], $row['2max']);
            } elseif ($random > $row['2percentage'] && $random < $row['3percentage'] || $random == $row['3percentage']) {
                $amount = rand($row['3min'], $row['3max']);
            } elseif ($random > $row['4percentage'] || $random == $row['4percentage']) {
                $amount = rand($row['4min'], $row['4max']);
            } else {
                exit("0");
            }

            echo $amount;
        }
}
```

But what it outputs is or 1 to 50, or 1001 to 10000.

So what did I do wrong?

Comment: I'd use `$random <= $row['1percentage']` instead of `$random < $row['1percentage'] || $random == $row['1percentage']`. It'll make easier to find the problem.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin I changed that but it still gives the same outputs..

Comment: @Strawberry the screenshot I send of the tables are from the database using `SELECT` nothing wrong in there..

Comment: @Just another youtube - screenshot is not MCVE, you should really create one. Also the screenshot is not the result of your SQL query, and judging by the screenshot your SQL query fails.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read the linked answer. Sorry, I don't do screenshots - but have fun.

Comment: Also `$row["1percentage"] + $row["2percentage"] + $row["3percentage"] + $row["4percentage"] + 1` will give you a result of `101`. Just out of curiosity - How can you have 101% chance to get random number? Even more: your algorithm will 100% give a random number between 0 and 101, and does not take into the account percentages at all.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code and the values in the database record you provided, your current setup will not work.

First, the `if` statements should be cleaned up as follows:

```
if ($_GET['method'] == "test") {
$sql = "SELECT 1percentage, 1min, 1max, 2percentage, 2min, 2max, 3percentage, 3min, 3max, 4percentage, 4min, 4max FROM `keys`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $total = $row['1percentage'] + $row['2percentage'] + $row['3percentage'] + $row['4percentage'] + 1;
        $random = rand(0, $total);
        if ($random <= $row['1percentage']) {
            $amount = rand($row['1min'], $row['1max']);
        } elseif ($random > $row['1percentage'] && $random <= $row['2percentage']) {
            $amount = rand($row['2min'], $row['2max']);
        } elseif ($random > $row['2percentage'] && $random <= $row['3percentage']) {
            $amount = rand($row['3min'], $row['3max']);
        } elseif ($random >= $row['4percentage']) {
            $amount = rand($row['4min'], $row['4max']);
        } else {
            exit("0");
        }

        echo $amount;
    }
```

}

This will not only make the script more efficient, but it will make the code more understandable and hopefully easier to debug.

Second, for this to work properly, you need to start with your smallest percentage in 1percentage and increase from there since your conditions use greater-than/less-than ranges between those values. For instance, look at the second condition:

```
if ($random > $row['1percentage'] && $random <= $row['2percentage'])
```

In the screenshot you posted, we see that 1percentage (75) is larger than 2percentage (20). Since no number can be larger than 75 and also less than or equal to 20, this condition will never be satisfied. Conditions 3 and 4 are similar. Therefore, the only two conditions that can possibly be satisfied are the first one, and the last one. With how it is currently set up, any number greater than or equal to 1percentage (75 in this case) will satisfy the first condition. Any number less than 1percentage and gretaer than or equal to 4percentage (1 in this case) will satisfy the last condition.

Either reorder your percentages in ascending order, or rewrite your conditions, and do some spot-checking to make sure you are getting the desired behavior.

**Another possible approach...**

As @Eugene Anisiutkin suggested, the algorithm itself needs some reworking. Assuming his following statement is correct...

*"The task is to generate random numbers from 1 to 50, with the generation probability 75%, from 51 to 200 with the generation probability 20%, from 201 to 1000 with the generation probability 4% and from 1001 to 10000 with the generation probability 1%."*

...then you would need to generate 75 random numbers from 1-50, 20 random number from 51-200, 4 random number from 201-1000, and 1 random number from 1001-10000. Having stored all of the randomly generated numbers in an array, you could then generate a final random number between 0 and the last index of that array (`count($randArray)-1`). That random number will be the index of the number you want to use from the array. Keep in mind, the "percentage" values will only be true percentages if they add up to 100. Otherwise, you can consider them more like a "weight". This approach would not require the "percentage" number to be in any kind of order. The code would look something like this:

```
if ($_GET['method'] == "test") {
$sql = "SELECT 1percentage, 1min, 1max, 2percentage, 2min, 2max, 3percentage, 3min, 3max, 4percentage, 4min, 4max FROM `keys`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //store the record values for easy reference
        $p1 = $row['1percentage'];
        $p1min = $row['1min'];
        $p1max = $row['1max'];
        $p2 = $row['2percentage'];
        $p2min = $row['2min'];
        $p2max = $row['2max'];
        $p3 = $row['3percentage'];
        $p3min = $row['3min'];
        $p3max = $row['3max'];
        $p4 = $row['4percentage'];
        $p4min = $row['4min'];
        $p4max = $row['4max'];

        $randomArray = array();

        for($i = 0; $i < $p1; $i++){
            $newRandom = rand($p1min, $p1max); //generate appropriate random number
            array_push($randomArray, $newRandom); //add the random number to the array
        }

        for($i = 0; $i < $p2; $i++){
            $newRandom = rand($p2min, $p2max); //generate appropriate random number
            array_push($randomArray, $newRandom); //add the random number to the array
        }

        for($i = 0; $ i < $p3; $i++){
            $newRandom = rand($p3min, $p3max); //generate appropriate random number
            array_push($randomArray, $newRandom); //add the random number to the array
        }

        for($i=0;$i<$p4;$i++){
            $newRandom = rand($p4min, $p4max); //generate appropriate random number
            array_push($randomArray, $newRandom); //add the random number to the array
        }

        //get last index of array
        $uBound = count($randomArray)-1;
        //get a random index
        $randomIndex = rand(0, $uBound);

        $amount = $randomArray[$randomIndex];

        echo $amount;
    }
```

}

Comment: It still won't work as intended, the algorithm itself is wrong. `$total = $row['1percentage'] + $row['2percentage'] + $row['3percentage'] + $row['4percentage'] + 1` gives you 101 and `$random = rand(0, $total);` gives a random value between 0 and 101, and that value has nothing to do with the percetages.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin, I agree, without knowing more about what they are trying to achieve, the current algorithm doesn't make sense. My answer was just a best attempt to explain why they are only seeing one of two conditions satisfied in any case. Once the initial issue is resolved, hopefully it either serves their particular purpose, or they can revise the algorithm more easily.

Comment: It's pretty clear to me what they are trying to achive. The task is to generate random numbers from 1 to 50, with the generation probability 75%, from 51 to 200 with the generation probability 20%, from 201 to 1000 with the generation probability 4% and from 1001 to 10000 with the generation probability 1%. It's not a simple task because the probability part only makes sense when you generate at least 100 numbers, better a 1000.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem that I would think that it has been solved before.

Python's `random.choices` function solves a quite similar problem to this.

Here is an attempt at converting this in PHP to suit the current use case.

```
# https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/bisect.py#L22
function bisect(array $a, float $x, int $lo, int $hi): int {
    $mid = $lo + $hi;
    while ($lo < $hi) {
        $mid = ($lo + $hi) / 2;
        if ($x < $a[$mid]) {
            $hi = $mid;
        } else {
            $lo = $mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return $lo;
}

/*
 * Generate a random number 
 * from 1 to 50, with the generation probability 75%,
 * from 51 to 200 with the generation probability 20%,
 * from 201 to 1000 with the generation probability 4% and 
 * from 1001 to 10000 with the generation probability 1%.
 */
function randomChoice(array $population, array $weights): int
{
    $cummWeights = array_reduce($weights, function ($acc, $curr) {
        $lastSlice = array_slice($acc, -1);
        $acc[] = $lastSlice[0] + $curr;
        return $acc;
    }, [0]);

    # remove 0 starting value
    array_shift($cummWeights);

    $lastWeightSlice = array_slice($cummWeights, -1);
    $total = $lastWeightSlice[0];

    $probability = ((float)rand() / (float)getrandmax());
    $needle = $probability * $total;

    # look for $needle in $cummWeights, then use that to select which population distribution to generate a random number from.
    # https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py#L387
    $index = bisect($cummWeights, $needle, 0, count($population));


    $distribution = $population[$index];
    return rand($distribution[0], $distribution[1]);
}

echo randomChoice(
    [
        [51, 200], 
        [1, 50], 
        [201, 1000], 
        [1001, 10000]
    ],
    [20, 75, 4, 1]
);
```

Comment: Wow, a far better solution. I thought about drawing a somewhat similar solution on paper, and then coding it, but unfortunatelly I didn't have the time.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time on this problem, I've came up with a slightly different solution. The realisation of probabilities in the example is bad, but it does show the basic exaple of achiving te needed probability for almost any amount of generated data. The code below will not work correctly if you set `$how_much_numbers_to_generate` variable lower than at least 50, but that's the way of probabilities. The data set has to be pretty big in order to get a somewhat accurate probability. Also in order for the example to work you must replace username, password and database in `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_name", "my_pass", "my_database");` with the ones you use. The full code is below

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_username", "my_password", "my_database");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$how_much_numbers_to_generate = 1000;

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 1percentage, 1min, 1max, 2percentage, 2min, 2max, 3percentage, 3min, 3max, 4percentage, 4min, 4max FROM percentages");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $first_percentage = $row['1percentage'];
    $first_min = $row['1min'];
    $first_max = $row['1max'];
    $second_percentage = $row['2percentage'];
    $second_min = $row['2min'];
    $second_max = $row['2max'];
    $third_percentage = $row['3percentage'];
    $third_min = $row['3min'];
    $third_max = $row['3max'];
    $fourth_percentage = $row['4percentage'];
    $fourth_min = $row['4min'];
    $fourth_max = $row['4max'];

    $first_numbers_generated=0;
    $second_numbers_generated=0;
    $third_numbers_generated=0;
    $fourth_numbers_generated=0;

    $random_array = array();

    for($numbers_generated=0; $numbers_generated < $how_much_numbers_to_generate; $numbers_generated++)
    {
        if( $first_numbers_generated==0 || $first_numbers_generated/$numbers_generated * 100.0 <=  $first_percentage)
        {
            $random_value = rand($first_min, $first_max);
            $first_numbers_generated++;
        }

        else if( $second_numbers_generated==0 || $second_numbers_generated/$numbers_generated * 100.0 <=  $second_percentage)
        {
            $random_value = rand($second_min, $second_max);
            $second_numbers_generated++;
        }

        else if( $third_numbers_generated==0 || $third_numbers_generated/$numbers_generated * 100.0 <=  $third_percentage)
        {
            $random_value = rand($third_min, $third_max);
            $third_numbers_generated++;
        }

        else if( $fourth_numbers_generated==0 || $fourth_numbers_generated/$numbers_generated * 100.0 <=  $fourth_percentage)
        {
            $random_value = rand($fourth_min, $fourth_max);
            $fourth_numbers_generated++;
        }
        else
        {
            $random_value = rand($first_min, $fourth_max);
            if ($random_value <= $first_max) 
            {
                $first_numbers_generated++;
            }
            else if ($random_value <= $second_max)
            {
                $second_numbers_generated++;
            }
            else if ($random_value <= $third_max)
            {
                $third_numbers_generated++;
            }
            else
            {
                $fourth_numbers_generated++;
            }
        }

        array_push($random_array, $random_value);
    }
    echo "First numbers generated: " . $first_numbers_generated . "<br/>";
    echo "Second numbers generated: " . $second_numbers_generated . "<br/>";
    echo "Third numbers generated: " . $third_numbers_generated . "<br/>";
    echo "Fourth numbers generated: " . $fourth_numbers_generated . "<br/>";
    echo "First probability: " . ($first_numbers_generated/$numbers_generated * 100.0) . "<br/>";
    echo "Second probability: " . ($second_numbers_generated/$numbers_generated * 100.0) . "<br/>";
    echo "Third probability: " . ($third_numbers_generated/$numbers_generated * 100.0) . "<br/>";
    echo "Fourth probability: " . ($fourth_numbers_generated/$numbers_generated * 100.0) . "<br/>";
}
```